# Duplicate rows in JSF/PF Datatable using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having a problem with a PrimeFaces (3.2) datatable that uses lazy loading, the data is loaded from a MySQL database using Hibernate (3.6).

The problem is that I'm getting duplicate results inside the datatable. I did a lot of research on this, mostly the problem is using "EAGER"-loading of OneToMany/ManyToOne/... relations. My entity has 5 ManyToOne and 1 OneToOne relations.

The results are loaded using a DAO and should return 2 rows. The datatable shows 4 rows in the following order:

1. Result 1
2. Result 2
3. Result 1
4. Result 2

A count(*)-query returns the correct number of rows (2).

Directly using the SQL-query which is logged when hibernate's "show_sql" switch is set to true it correctly returned 2 rows.

While at first some of these relations were eager-loaded, I changed all of them to lazy loading with no success. I debugged my DAO-method which correctly returns 2 rows. The data is then loaded into the primefaces datatable and gets duplicated somewhere.

I then tried the same using another user-account and saw that there are no duplicate rows.

I then deleted all records of the relevant entity from the database without any success.

I really don't know what the problem might be here. I even eliminated all of the ManyToOne/... relations and directly mapped the foreign keys as Integer values to avoid any joins and nothing changed.

I don't know what parts of the code might help you, but if it's needed I can share it with you.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[Edit]
Using a result-transformer and mapping the entities to a Set instead of a List didn't help either, the database and therefore hibernate always returns the correct number of rows, but something must be happening somewhere in between the DAO and the Datatable.

[Edit 2]
After some more investigation, I realised that this only happens when the pageSize for the pagination is set to 15 (there are 3 possible values to select from: 5, 10 and 15).

When set to 10 everything works as expected. I really don't get what is wrong with this, because the same code with a different entity works on another page.

Comment: It seems that this is related to when the rowCount-property of the lazydatamodel is set. After changing it's position inside the class, it works. Strange enough the same code works in another datatable which has the exact same functionality with another entity class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works if I change the mapped fields of the class that is listed, from EAGER to LAZY. No difference changing pageSize (*Edit 2). 
In addition, I had to add to web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in order to avoid getting this error  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException...no session or session was closed